# asp session proper usage and possible interface usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

the code i'm using is below.  Is this the proper way to use Session?  also how do I call companyID and userID to clarify, if i did Session. is it Session.Contents or Session.Keys?  this is my first time using session, I know I use httpcontact.current.user to access most of this but i'm not sure how to access each part of the data.

Thanks!

```
    MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=users; User=root;Password=00;");
    cn.Open();

    string storedProcedureName = "VLID";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedureName, cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", this.Login1.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@passwordID", this.Login1.Password);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        string userID = dr["userID"].ToString();

        string companyID = dr["CompanyID"].ToString();
        string sessionID = Session.SessionID.ToString();
        Session.Add(companyID, "companyID");
        Session.Add(userID, "userID");
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Response.Redirect("index.html");
        // Event Authenticate is true  
    }
```

Comment: Why did you declared string sessionID variable? You are not using it anywhere. I would have create a user profile struct which would holder the company id, user id and any other information and add it to the session. it is just another way manage the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling Session.Add method a little backwards:

`Session.Add` takes a key and a value, in that order; therefore, on your code you want:

```
Session.Add("companyID",companyID );
Session.Add("userID",userID );
```

But instead, you could do this, too:

```
Session["companyID"]=companyID;
Session["userID"]=userID;
```

Then, whenever you need to retrieve the userID value that you stored previously, you can do:

```
string userID= Session["userID"] as string;
```

As a side note, I wouldn't mix data access code on the UI code as you are doing.

The code that gets the data from the database should be moved to the data access layer (DAL).

And when you instantiate a database connection, always enclose it in an `using` statement so that is properly disposed when it comes out of scope:

```
using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=users; User=root;Password=00;"))
{
    cn.Open();
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: understood, if I wanted to call using Session.keys I would have to create an interface right?  Do you have an example of how to add session to an interface.  I want to avoid having to input the exact Session["whateverhere"] for each time I want to call it.

Comment: @Mike what do you mean by `adding session to an interface`? `Session` is basically a `Dictionary` with key,value pairs.

Comment: well heres my question, when I reference this session in my pages using HttpContext.Current do I use Session or do I use User, so If i want to use the userId in a parameter in a stored procedure I would use what to retrieve that seesion userID i just added?

Comment: string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"] as string;?

Comment: is there any benefit to storing session information in an interface?

Comment: You can't store **anything** on an `interface`. Interfaces don't have implementation. I don't understand what are you referring to.